# How to selectively allow only a few methods to be accessed concurrently using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I am using Flask + Python for exposing few API(s). Currently, I have made flask as multi-threaded by specifying

```
app.run(threaded=True)
```

But, my requirement is that, I want all "GET" methods to be handled in parallel, whereas the POST, PUT or DELETE methods should be queued.

Is there a way to achieve this using Flask and Python?